# WebStorm inspection error for Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, webstorm

I'm having trouble disabling a WebStorm inspection notification. I've disabled all inspections and the notification still persists.

Basically I try to give the command (import "anything") inside an if condition and return error (but when I run the Meteor works fine). When I remove the "import" command from the condition, the notification disappears.

```
//Works well
if(1 ==1){
    console.log("Hello world")
}

//On Meteor works well, but WebStorm informs "statement expected"
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    import "/imports/client/views/backoffice/activities/ads/ad/layout/admin_ad_layout"
}

//Works well
import "/imports/client/views/backoffice/activities/ads/ad/layout/admin_ad_layout"
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use Atom with meteor plugin.

Comment: such conditional imports doesn't seem to be a part of any spec... WebStorm provides basic support for async import() function (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#dynamic-import-expressions), but the syntax like above will unlikely be supported

Comment: Ankur, thanks for the suggestion. I'm fascinated by Atom.

Comment: Lena, of course. Atom met my needs.Thanks.